# Symfony2 form collections

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, symfony-forms

I've this in my database:

[image: A product vitamin contains a product, a vitamin and a value]

Now, I want to able to add products and product_vitamins through a single form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', null, array(
        'description' => 'The name of the product'));

    $builder->add('product_vitamins', 'collection', array(
        'type'  => new ProductVitaminType(),
        'allow_add'   => true,
    ));
}
```

My ProductVitaminType looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('vitamin_id', null, array(
        'description'   => 'The vitamin id'));

    $builder->add('value', null, array(
        'description' => 'The value of this vitamin'));

    $builder->addEventSubscriber(new PartialFormBindSubscriber());
}
```

I send this to my backend and all properties (also of the relationships) will be populated correctly:

```
{
    "food_product" : {
        "name" : "foo",
        "product_vitamins" : [
            {"vitamin_id" :  9, "value" : 52},
            {"vitamin_id" :  4, "value" : 52},
            {"vitamin_id" :  5, "value" : 52},
            {"vitamin_id" :  2, "value" : 52},
            {"vitamin_id" :  8, "value" : 52}
        ]
    }
}
```

However, the product_id of the product_vitamins are null, so I get this error on persisting:

```
Unable to execute INSERT statement [INSERT INTO `Food_Product_Vitamin` (`vitamin_id`, `value`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3)] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Food_Product_Vitamin`, CONSTRAINT `Food_Product_Vitamin_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `Food_Product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)]
```

I dont understand the problem, because it should save the product first and then it should have a product_id.

### Update: Controller Action

```
public function putProductsAction(Request $request)
{
    $model = new Product();
    $type  = new ProductType();
    $form  = $this->formFactory->create($type, $model);

    return $form->isValid() ? $model->save() : $form;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of the controller.

Comment: Hey. I've added the controller code.

Comment: See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html to associate the Vitamin to the Product.

Comment: Well, I got the code from the docs site, which you've posted. Could you explain your answer in more detail please?

Comment: In your controller, you don't associate anything. But it seems that you do this in `$model->save()`, can you add this code please?